# Multiple touchable options component in scrollview react native is re-rendering to the top when there is change in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

This is my react-native app where i'm rendering multiple touchable components in a long scrollView, everything is working as expected but the scroll view component is rendering to the top of the scrollView when I make changes in the component (select/di-select), but I think the expected behavior is to remain to the portion where I've made the selection, instead every time I select an option from the bottom of the component the scroll view goes to the top.

These are the image for the end result of the code

[image: Top of the component]

[image: Bottom of the component]

This is my code for the rendering the scrollView

```
  const creativityOptions = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'art',
    },
    {id: 2, name: 'design'},
    {id: 3, name: 'making-videos'},
    {id: 4, name: 'make-up'},
    {id: 5, name: 'photography'},
    {id: 6, name: 'writing'},
    {id: 7, name: 'singing'},
    {id: 8, name: 'dancing'},
    {id: 9, name: 'crafts'},
  ];

  const [fieldValue, setFiledValue] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    dob: new Date(),
    interests: {
      creativity: [],
      sports: [],
      stayingIn: [],
      tvFilm: [],
      reading: [],
      music: [],
      foodsDrink: [],
      travelling: [],
      pets: [],
    },
  });

  const setInterestValue = (item, option) => {
    if (fieldValue.interests[item].some(item => item.id == option.id)) {
      var filtered = fieldValue.interests[item].filter(
        val => val.id !== option.id,
      );

      setFiledValue({
        ...fieldValue,
        interests: {...fieldValue.interests, [item]: filtered},
      });
    } else {
      if (lengthOfInterest <= 7) {
        setFiledValue({
          ...fieldValue,
          interests: {
            ...fieldValue.interests,
            [item]: [...fieldValue.interests[item], option],
          },
        });
      }
    }
  };
  const RenderInterest = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingBottom: 80}}>
          <Text
            F24
            M
            style={{
              color: Colors.black,
              marginTop: 50,
              marginHorizontal: 20,
            }}>
            Your Interest
          </Text>
          <DynamicTouchableComponent
            title="Creativity"
            options={creativityOptions}
            selectedOptions={fieldValue.interests.creativity}
            selectedOptionsCallback={options =>
              setInterestValue('creativity', options)
            }
          />
          <DynamicTouchableComponent
            title="Sports"
            options={sportsOption}
            selectedOptions={fieldValue.interests.sports}
            selectedOptionsCallback={options =>
              setInterestValue('sports', options)
            }
          />
          <DynamicTouchableComponent
            title="Staying In"
            options={stayingInOptions}
            selectedOptions={fieldValue.interests.stayingIn}
            selectedOptionsCallback={options =>
              setInterestValue('stayingIn', options)
            }
          />
          <DynamicTouchableComponent
            title="Film & TV"
            options={filmTVOptions}
            selectedOptions={fieldValue.interests.tvFilm}
            selectedOptionsCallback={options =>
              setInterestValue('tvFilm', options)
            }
          />
          <DynamicTouchableComponent
            title="Reading"
            options={readingOptions}
            selectedOptions={fieldValue.interests.reading}
            selectedOptionsCallback={options =>
              setInterestValue('reading', options)
            }
          />
          <DynamicTouchableComponent
            title="Music"
            options={musicOptions}
            selectedOptions={fieldValue.interests.music}
            selectedOptionsCallback={options =>
              setInterestValue('music', options)
            }
          />
          <DynamicTouchableComponent
            title="Food & Drink"
            options={foodDrinkOptions}
            selectedOptions={fieldValue.interests.foodsDrink}
            selectedOptionsCallback={options =>
              setInterestValue('foodsDrink', options)
            }
          />
          <DynamicTouchableComponent
            title="Travelling"
            options={travelOptions}
            selectedOptions={fieldValue.interests.travelling}
            selectedOptionsCallback={options =>
              setInterestValue('travelling', options)
            }
          />
          <DynamicTouchableComponent
            title="Pets"
            options={petsOptions}
            selectedOptions={fieldValue.interests.pets}
            selectedOptionsCallback={options =>
              setInterestValue('pets', options)
            }
          />
        </ScrollView>
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 0,
            height: 70,
            width: '100%',
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.4}
              disabled={lengthOfInterest >= 1}
              style={{
                paddingLeft: 20,
              }}
              onPress={() => {}}>
              <Text
                F18
                R
                style={{
                  color: lengthOfInterest >= 1 ? Colors.grayDark : Colors.black,
                }}>
                Skip
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginRight: 30,
              }}>
              <Text
                F16
                R
                style={{
                  color: Colors.black,
                  marginRight: 15,
                }}>
                {`${lengthOfInterest}/8`}
              </Text>
              <NextButton
                style={{
                  backgroundColor:
                    lengthOfInterest >= 1 ? Colors.primaryDark : Colors.border,
                }}
                disabled={lengthOfInterest < 1}
                iconStyle={
                  lengthOfInterest >= 1 ? Colors.black : Colors.grayDark
                }
                onPress={() => {
                  // setShowInterest(false);
                  // setPageIndex(pageIndex + 1);

                  handleSignup();
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

This is for the Dynamic component where the options are rendered

```
export const DynamicTouchableComponent = ({
  title,
  options,
  style,
  selectedOptionsCallback,
  selectedOptions,
}) => {
  const setInterest = index => {
    const selectedvalue = options[index];
    selectedOptionsCallback(selectedvalue);
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}>
      <Text
        F22
        M
        style={{
          color: Colors.black,
          marginTop: 30,
          marginLeft: 10,
        }}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <View
        style={[
          {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
            flexGrow: 1,
          },
          style,
        ]}>
        {options.map((option, index) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={index}
              style={[
                styles.option2,
                {
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  backgroundColor: selectedOptions.some(
                    item => item.id == option.id,
                  )
                    ? Colors.primary
                    : Colors.white,
                  paddingVertical: 6,
                  paddingHorizontal: 10,
                  borderColor: Colors.primary,
                  marginHorizontal: 10,
                },
              ]}
              onPress={() => {
                setInterest(index);
              }}>
              <Text
                F14
                R
                style={{
                  color: selectedOptions.some(item => item.id == option.id)
                    ? Colors.white
                    : Colors.headingGray,
                  textTransform: 'capitalize',
                }}>
                {option.name}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```